# how to remove a tag in the_category function

Tags: functions, categories, css

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L0

line:195

```
       //line 195
     default:
             $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( 
         $category->term_id ) ) . '" ' . $rel . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';


//exact php function       
     <?php the_category(); ?>

//output from inspector
<ul class="post-categories">
  <li><a href="/category/poker/" rel="category tag">poker</a></li>
</ul>
```

im using twenty seventeen theme the problem is

everytime i post the exact function and when I inpect it in any browser it display css.how i remove those a tag?

Note: the output must be poker which is the category, line 195 is causing the problem

Comment: `the_category()` is specifically for outputting a link. Can you please provide more information about what you are wanting to display, and where you're trying to display it? Are you trying to show just the name of the category a post is in, on the individual post?

Comment: what i mean is the function <?php the_category(); ?> suppose to display exact category name, so what is happening is displaying including the class

Comment: It's built into the function. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L0 You can use a different function to get just the info you need or build your own `<ul>` without a class manually.

Comment: yeah i've read it, ill try my luck manipulating those code.

Comment: @WebElaine having hard time finding what to delete in this code

Comment: Never modify core files. Instead try different functions. For example, you can call `get_the_category();` which returns an object with the category information, like the link and title, and then if it isn't empty, output your `<ul>` and manually build the `<li>`.